# Communication between two independent QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt

There are two separate QT Designer ui forms.Both have two buttons. When button in form1 is clicked, form2 opens. How to sent a message to form1 when button in form2 is clicked. All works properly but the message.

**form1.py**

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import form2                            #Import for Signal
from form2 import *                     # Import for UI
RegForm = "regform.ui"
Ui_RegForm, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(RegForm)
class RegForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_RegForm):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(RegForm,self).__init__(parent,flags =                  Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.unHideBtn.clicked.connect(self.showUnhideForm)

        self.myForm = form2.UnhideForm(self)                 #For Signal
        self.myForm.mySignal.connect(self.receiveSignal)     #Signal

    def receiveSignal(self, message):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', message)

    def showUnhideForm(self):
        sub = UnhideForm(self)
        sub.show()
```

**form2.py**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
UnhideForm = "unhide.ui"
Ui_UnhideForm, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(UnhideForm)
class UnhideForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_UnhideForm):
    mySignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)#Signal
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super(UnhideForm,self).__init__(parent,flags = Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # On clicking emit a signal
        self.quitBtn.clicked.connect(self.emitSignal)

        # And Close the form
        self.quitBtn.clicked.connect(self.close)
    def emitSignal(self):
        if(not self.signalsBlocked()):
            self.mySignal.emit("Yes")
```

Form2 opens properly and closes when quitBtn is cliked. But no message is sent back to the Form1. I am new to PyQt. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the example code for sent a message to one UI to another UI

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class FORM1 (QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FORM1, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button1 = QtGui.QPushButton (self)
        self.button1.setGeometry (QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 100, 30))
        self.button1.setObjectName ('button1')
        self.button1.setText ('Button1')        

        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry (QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 400, 100))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName('textEdit')         

        self.resize(500, 200)

        self.button1.clicked.connect (self.callForm2)     


    def callForm2 (self) :
        self.form2_widget     = FORM2 ()
        self.form2_widget.show  ()            
        self.form2_widget.button2.clicked.connect (self.sendMessage)     

    def sendMessage (self) :        
        self.textEdit.setText ('There are two separate QT Designer ui forms.Both have two buttons.')     



class FORM2 (QtGui.QWidget) :  

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FORM2, self).__init__(parent)        

        self.button2    = QtGui.QPushButton (self)
        self.button2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 100, 30))
        self.button2.setObjectName ('Button2')
        self.button2.setText ('Button2')        

        self.resize(400, 100) 


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = FORM1 ()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: If this solves your problem, you are encouraged to accept the answer. I would prefer a little explanation in the answer of what was done.